# RestTemplate with POST request not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman, resttemplate

I am trying to call a service in another Spring Boot application using RestTemplate,like below:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String getHi() {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8082/hello", String.class);
    }
}
```

This is the Main class for application A:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceApplication {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Below the other Spring Boot application B:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    
    @RequestMapping ("/hello")

    public String getHi() {
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

Application A (RestTemplate): In this I am trying to achieve the API call to go through like, Postman -> Application A -> Application B. I tried this API with Postman, but the request is not sent. Just showing "Sending request...". Also didn't get failure response.

Application B: Called GET endpoint from Postman which invokes `getHi()` in
Controller(RestController) class in Postman and browser, both work fine.

Port used:

- Application A: 8083
- Application B: 8082

Both applications are running. I have gone through lots of websites and git codes, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Are you sure you’re not recursing on the call? Is 8082 definitely the port for the one that just returns ‘hi’?

Comment: @BeUndead if I run springboot application with service, then everything works fine. Like,able to get response in postman as well in browser. But if I try with RestTemplate application, then not working. If paste the url in browser, then it keeps loading. Same in postman.

Comment: You need BOTH of them running, and to make sure your RestTemplate calls the OTHER service. Otherwise your RestTemplate will just call back to the method it came from and keep looping. Hence why it never loads.

Comment: Your description would be clearer when you use certain names for the services, even if it is something simple as "service 1" and "service 2" and then stick to that. This would make it clearer which status matches to which service. Especially your bold text is a bit ambiguous in its current state.

Comment: @BeUndead yes I am running both of them. I have edited my question for clear points. Please check once

Comment: @Tom I have edited my question. Hope this clear to understand

Comment: Yes that's better. I fixed some grammar and mind that I also switched the names app A and B to match the order of the shown code.

Comment: @Tom okay now looks fine

Comment: I've tested your code and it works fine. Can request both services and both respond with "Hi". Test app A by letting it just return "Hi" (like app B) and see if that works. When you say the request isn't sent from Postman, then your connection to app A is faulty. Check the Spring logs when starting it, make sure the port is correct.

Comment: @Tom I've done as you said. Now Application A just returns "Hi" string. This works fine. But I've used RestTemplate in App  A to send the message or any objects to App B. That is not happening. I am doing this to practice RestTemplate

Comment: Now you know App A works generally, so now you can text if that App has network access and if it can see App B by requesting data from any other website. If that works, then App A has internet access and the connection to App B is faulty.

Comment: @Tom Thank you so much for your help. Now everything works fine.